# TypeScript: Split array according to the numbers sign and fill up the rest with null objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, split

So I have a little Problem,

I have an Array of objects and want to split them according to the numbers sign.
The objects should then be stored dynamically in different Arrays, but keep their index and be filled with zero at the front and back. Then different Arrays are stored in a single Array.

Example:

```js
const arr = [
    { date: dayjs('12.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: 30 },
    { date: dayjs('13.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: -30 },
    { date: dayjs('14.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: -30 },
    { date: dayjs('15.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: 90 },
];
```

Current Output:

```
[ { date: 2020-12-01T23:00:00.000Z, profitValue: 30 } ]
[ { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: -30 }, { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: -30 } ]
[ { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: 90 } ]
```

Predicted Output:

```
[ { date: 2020-12-01T23:00:00.000Z, profitValue: 30 }, null , null, null ]
[ null, { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: -30 }, { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: -30 }, null ]
[ null, null, null, { date: Invalid Date, profitValue: 90 } ]
```

This is my code so far, since I am a beginner, it is probably badly solved.
Unfortunately I do not know how to fill the array.

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";
const arr = [
    { date: dayjs('12.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: 30 },
    { date: dayjs('13.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: -30 },
    { date: dayjs('14.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: -30 },
    { date: dayjs('15.02.2020').toDate(), profitValue: 90 },
];
function splitArrayBySign() {

    let sign = Math.sign(arr[0].profitValue);
    let datasets = [];
    let dataset = [];
    for (const i in arr) {
        if (sign === Math.sign(arr[i].profitValue)) {
            dataset.push(arr[i]);
        }
        else {
            datasets.push(dataset);
            dataset = [];
            dataset.push(arr[i]);
        }
        sign = Math.sign(arr[i].profitValue);
    }
    datasets.push(dataset);
    return datasets;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what dayjs is so I ignored it and used this as the const instead:

```
var arr = [
    { date: '12.02.2020', profitValue: 30 },
    { date: '13.02.2020', profitValue: -30 },
    { date: '14.02.2020', profitValue: -30 },
    { date: '15.02.2020', profitValue: 90 },
];
```

With that in mind you can achieve what you're looking for like this:

```
var result = arr.reduce((accum, record, index) => {     
    var group = accum[accum.length - 1];
    //if we're the first group OR the sign is different
    if(!group || Math.sign(group[group.length - 1].profitValue) !== Math.sign(record.profitValue)){ 
        group = [];
        accum.push(group);
        //fill up the new grouping with nulls at the beginning
        for(var x = 0; x < index; x++){
            group.push(null);
        }       
    }   
    group.push(record);
    return accum;
}, []).map(group => {
    //fill up the grouping with nulls at the end
    for(var x = group.length; x < arr.length; x++){
        group.push(null);
    }
    return group;
});
```

Which produces this output:

```
[
    [
        {"date":"12.02.2020","profitValue":30},
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        null,
        {"date":"13.02.2020","profitValue":-30}, 
        {"date":"14.02.2020","profitValue":-30},
        null
    ],
    [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {"date":"15.02.2020","profitValue":90}]
    ]
]
```